# Video element in react does not play the stream

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, webcam

The html video element below does not play the webcam stream.
setState works fine since the browser notifies me that the site is accessing the camera.
It still invokes the webcam but the html video element is not activated after state change.
What i see is the black screen even if the webcam is active.
There are no error messages on browser console
any help appreciated

```
 import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import  Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
    
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    
    const styles = () => ({
      root: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        width: "20%",
        height: "25%",
        overflowY: "auto",
      },
      videoPreview:{
        alignSelf: "center",
        width: "30%",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
        marginTop: 20,
      },
    });
    
    const Preview = (props) => {
      const {classes} = props;
      const [videoPreviewTrack, setVideoPreviewTrack] = useState(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}) );
      useEffect(() => {
     //something here maybe?
      });
    
    
        return (
          <div className={classes.videoPreview}>
          <video src={videoPreviewTrack} autoPlay={true} id={"videoPreviewElement"}>
          </video ></div>
      );
    };
    
    Preview.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    
    
    
    export default connect()(withStyles(styles)(Preview));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {useState,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import  Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "20%",
    height: "25%",
    overflowY: "auto",
  },
  previewBackground:{
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  videoPreview:{
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: "15%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});

const Preview = (props) => {
  const {classes} = props;
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getVideo();
  }, [videoRef]);

  const getVideo = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia( {video:  true} )
    .then(stream => {
      let video = videoRef.current;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("error:", err);
    });
  };

    return (<div align={"center"} className={classes.previewBackground} >
      <div   >
      <video className={classes.videoPreview} ref={videoRef} >
        </video >
      </div>
        </div>
  );
};

Preview.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};



export default (withStyles(styles)(Preview));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

for those who struggle to play video in react.js here
is the sample code

```
 var videoRef =  useRef(null)

const getOurVideoStream = async() => {
try {
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
console.log(videoRef)
   let video = videoRef.current
   video.srcObject = stream
   video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", ()=>{
      video.play()
   })


} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

}

```
  useEffect(() => {
      getOurVideoStream()
  },[])

 <video className='video-box' ref={videoRef}></video>
```